# Confirm checked list box

Tags: c#, winforms

In the below code I am trying to output a message to confirm if a checkbox was ticked or not. How do I go about checking each box?

```cs
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Validate input data

    //check if a dvd was entered
    //here i want to check to see if any of my check boxes were ticked.
    if (chkDVD == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No DVD Selected!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    //Save data in DVDs File

    //Display Confirmation Message
    MessageBox.Show("DVD Succesfully removed!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: You check if `chkDVD.Checked` is true or not... Did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a standard WinForms checkbox, then all you need is to replace your current if statement with the following line:

```
if (!chkDVD.Checked)
```

If not, please post more of your code relating to what checkboxes you have.